# Which Android emulators to create to get a representative sample of different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I'm building a mobile app and want to test it on a variety of screen sizes while developing.

The app will be running on both Android and iOS, but my main dev machine is not a mac.

Which emulators should I create to get a representative sample of all different phone configurations, e.g small, medium, tablet, etc?

Answer (score 0):

if you will open avd manager and tap on create virtual device, you will see all types of devices listed having difference density categories.. most devices are xxhdpi.. so you can choose xxhdpi device out if them.However, you ca choose other screen density device and test on them. if you wanna check touch responsiveness, emulators dont work well.

Comment: My question is more about which emulators to create out of all the options in AVD, to have a representative sample of all the different sizes.

Comment: what's your purpose.. ?? different screen sizes ony matters if you have seperate layouts based on screen sizes. if you have no such thing.. choose whatever it wants.. behavuot does not change much.. most developers code different layouts for say above 600 dp width scree which would be a tablet,, less than that would be a phone.. choose any of pixel devices and you are good to go... create one tablet virtual device and one for phone..